# What do we do with click bait questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there a usefulness in having a hover function for a question - to see the question in a hover box, to avoid clicking on it to see what it's about? I feel some questions generate a 'hot topic' status simply because of this 'need to click' to see what on earth is going on... who'd ask such a thing... why?!

Often such questions get closed, but only after 2000 clicks! They are probably off-topic anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Question titles should not be click-bait and should be edited to clearly identify what they concern. Feel free to edit question titles yourself if they seem click-baity to you.